# Trying to make a password generator

Tags: java, passwords, generator

I'm trying to make a password generator using ASCII values with a menu option for lowercase letters, lowercase and uppercase, with numbers, etc.

I got the program to work for just lowercase but I don't know how to group it so the random number chooses multiple ASCII groups. We can't use arrays in this class either since we haven't covered those yet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Password {
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("              Password Generation Menu");   
System.out.println("====================================================");
System.out.println("[1] Lowercase Letters");
System.out.println("[2] Lowercase & Uppercase");
System.out.println("[3] Lowercase, Uppercase, and Numbers");
System.out.println("[4] Lowercase, Uppercase, Numbers, and Punctuation");
System.out.println("[5] Quit");
System.out.println("====================================================");
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Enter Selection: ");
int choice = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter Length of Password: ");
int n = in.nextInt();




for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){


        if(choice == 1){
            Random r = new Random();
            char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
            System.out.print(c);    
        }

        else if(choice == 2){
            Random r = new Random();
            char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'A');
            System.out.print(c);
        }

        else if(choice == 3){
            Random r = new Random();
            char c = (char)(r.nextInt(10) + '0');
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        else if(choice == 4){
            Random r = new Random();
            char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        else{
            System.exit(0);
        }
}


}
}
```

Comment: You mean like adding `choice = r.nextInt(4)+1;` in your for-loop?

Comment: Off topic: in a real word project you might use a [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html), which is a specialized implementation of `Random` producing "cryptographically strong random numbers".

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a random number that decides out of which class the next letter is taken and then generate another random number to select the actual letter out of that specific group.